# JMeter: How to parameterize a variable if its in POST request?

Tags: post, dynamic, jmeter, request

I have a variable in json as:

{
"myid":"01_wer4tdfhhsbigtscf"
}

The above value is nowhere to be seen in any previous requests and hence unable to capture the value. How may I get it?

Answer (score 0):

If it's cannot be correlated - then you can only leave it as is (hard-code) or use any of [other JMeter parameterization](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide/) approaches like:

- [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
- [Database via JDBC Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html)
- [Redis Data Set](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RedisDataSet/)
- etc.

If you have a list of IDs, i.e. one per virtual user you can put these IDs into CSV file, database, redis, whatever and configure JMeter to read the next value with each thread (virtual user)

Comment: the value is dynamic actually

Comment: If it is not present in response body/[headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)/URL then it's calculated somewhere somehow, probably by [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/DEFAULT.asp), if this is the case - you will need to replicate the calculation logic using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: there is no calculation, its just some random input. Please let me know how to handle

Comment: If you need to generate a random string - go for [__RandomString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString), you can inline functions directly into your request body. See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept